# Is there a solution for update one of the Json value of a key in Redis, while the Json is a value of a Redis key?

Tags: json, redis, apache-nifi

I have this Json value for 'x' key in Redis:

`{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}`

in Apache Nifi, I have this flowfile content with the same Json key:

`{"key2":"value3"}`

I want to update the value of 'x' key in Redis without removing 'key1' key and value.

Is it possible to change the Json value of a key in Redis key's value?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can simply do the following:

```
redis> JSON.SET j $ '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
OK
redis> JSON.SET j $.key2 '"value3"'
OK
redis> JSON.GET j $
"[{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value3\"}]"
```

You can also do it with [JSON.MERGE](https://redis.io/commands/json.merge/) (available since [Redis Stack](https://redis.io/docs/about/about-stack/) 7.2)

```
redis> JSON.SET j $ '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
OK
redis> JSON.MERGE j $ '{"key2":"value3"}'
OK
redis> JSON.GET j $
"[{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value3\"}]"
```

Comment: Thank you.
Do you know anything about how can I implement these queries in Apache Nifi and do this update Redis Json value by Nifi?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Apache Nifi.